# splitting xml root into two branches - with option of removing unwanted attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, transformation

The problem is really similar to my previous one (how to split xml root into two branches - with all but a specific child in the first branch and the specific child in the second).

As previously I have a file:

```
<config width="100" height="200">
    <parameter name="account number" country="UK">
        12345678901234567890123456
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="client code" codeType="xa">
        UK0112
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="email-address" accepts="yes">
        john.sparrow@rex.co.uk
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="postal-code" country="UK">
        W1A 1HQ
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="additional parameters" mode="on">
        <parameter name="preferences" type="internal">
            Not applicable
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="issues" type="internal" category="normal">
            None
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="complaints" type="internal">
            None
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="approbation" type="external">
            X11
        </parameter>
    </parameter>
</config>
```

This time I want to disentangle one arbitrary child with the name "issues" and put it into separate branch and keep all of the attributes of every node (for example width, or height or any additional that may exist e.g. color) - the solution was provided by ABach (thanks). Now the difference is that I want to remove the attribute category before moving the node into the separate branch

```
<configs>
    <config width="100" height="200">
        <parameter name="account number" country="UK">
            12345678901234567890123456
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="client code" codeType="xa">
            UK0112
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="email-address" accepts="yes">
            john.sparrow@rex.co.uk
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="postal-code" country="UK">
            W1A 1HQ
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="additional parameters" mode="on">
            <parameter name="preferences" type="internal">
                Not applicable
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="complaints" type="internal">
                None
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="approbation" type="external">
                X11
            </parameter>
        </parameter>
    </config>
    <config width="100" height="200">
        <parameter name="issues" type="internal">
                None
        </parameter>
    </config>
<configs>
```

The choice of the child and its parent is hard coded (parameter/parameter) and based on attribute name (issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <configs>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </configs>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="config[parameter/parameter/@name = 'issues']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates 
           select="parameter/parameter[@name = 'issues']"
           mode="extract" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parameter/parameter[@name = 'issues']" />

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="extract">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[local-name() != 'category'] | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample input, the result is:

```
<configs>
  <config width="100" height="200">
    <parameter name="account number" country="UK">
      12345678901234567890123456
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="client code" codeType="xa">
      UK0112
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="email-address" accepts="yes">
      john.sparrow@rex.co.uk
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="postal-code" country="UK">
      W1A 1HQ
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="additional parameters" mode="on">
      <parameter name="preferences" type="internal">
        Not applicable
      </parameter>
      <parameter name="complaints" type="internal">
        None
      </parameter>
      <parameter name="approbation" type="external">
        X11
      </parameter>
    </parameter>
  </config>
  <config width="100" height="200">
    <parameter name="issues" type="internal">
      None
    </parameter>
  </config>
</configs>
```